# How can I wait for a window title to be updated?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When i open a window it first has false title(still not updated) after several seconds title updates, is there any function or a practical solution to wait for this so then i could send a message somewhere when this happens...

What i have is a cbt hook that gets wparam when window activates, i need to wait for this wparam to become real title(not the fake one)

I can put a sleep for every activation but that would slow everything down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your target window is following the standard method to update its caption, you can add a hook to catch the precise moment when the caption has changed.

To do this, you will need to add a windows message return hook with `SetWindowsHookEx`, passing it a `CallWndRetProc` handler from your code to receive notices upon completion of windows messages by the target window's message handler.

[SetWindowsHookEx() @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[CallWndRetProc @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The windows message you need to trap is `WM_SETTEXT`, which is sent to trigger the change in the default text/caption for a window.

[WM_SETTEXT @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you would like to test this in isolation, `WM_SETTEXT` is an implicit message sent upon calling `SetWindowText` to change the window text/caption.

[SetWindowText() @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, you might also be able to get rid of your cbt hook, as `WM_ACTIVATE`, `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`, and `WM_SETFOCUS` can be trapped with the same hook used to trap `WM_SETTEXT`. These messages cover various levels of activation activity and type for windows.

[WM_ACTIVATE @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_MOUSEACTIVATE @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645612%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_SETFOCUS @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Last, if the target window is a window you create and control in your own process, you could simply intercept those windows messages instead of using hooks. If it is impossible to use your available frameworks to intercept those messages, `SetClassLongPtr` is also another alternative, which may be used to implement a subclass for that type of window to allow you to intercept window messages. If you use this method, you would delegate all calls to the original windows message handler, and only act during a return from the original procedure upon receiving a message of interest.

[SetClassLongPtr() @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633589%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[WindowProc @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in c#:

Set up a listener for the textchanged event.

```
this.something.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(something_TextChanged);
```

Then setup the code that will do whatever you need when the text changes

```
void something_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```